# Synchronise the update of all @Published items in an ObservableObject at the same time

Tags: ios, swiftui, combine

I have a function that updates different `@Published` variables within an `ObservableObject`. They aren't updated all at the same time due to processing times of my algorithm between assignments.

Is there any clever way to delay the publishing of updates of variables to observers of my class? Something like manually blocking the publishing and then manually publishing when the function has finished?

Another way could be to do all the calculations and then assign the values to the variables at the end, but even then I'm assuming it probably won't be an exactly synchronised update?

Comment: Seems like there are a couple of options: 1) Have only one `@Published` property (basically a flag that everything is done) and set it when all others are assigned 2) Have *no* `@Published` properties and call `objectWillChange` manually 3) As you mentioned, assign all variables at the same time (which will essentially be synchronized since your observers will see the changes on the next run loop)

Comment: Just to elaborate on point 1 of the comment by @jnpdx: you could also use a struct to encapsulate the values that get updated together. An instance of this struct can be your single Published property (as opposed to using a flag). When updates are performed, you create a new instance of the struct to hold the new values and assign it to the published property.

Answer (score 0):

Look at using `zip`. It will wait until all the attached publishers emit a value before emitting a tuple that contains all of them.